# Why the loss value of Adam solver is strating to increase after 100k iterations?

Tags: caffe, pycaffe, matcaffe

I had already trained the CNN with SGD, and it is training well. However, once I am training the model with Adam solver, after `100k` iteration almost, it is starting to increase the loss value. Could you please help me to interpret this?

[image]

The following shows the `solver.prototxt`:

```
momentum: 0.99
momentum2: 0.999  #+
test_interval: 1000
test_iter: 40
weight_decay: 0.0005
base_lr:       0.0001
```

Comment: you are overfitting

Comment: @Shai yes it is overfitting, however, I do not know should I train the model only for 60-70k iterations? Then, will I be able to use the model for inference? 
The reason that I posted is why it is starting to overfit after some iterations?